# Raspberry Pi OpenVG C/C++

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi3, openvg

I have two question about `OpenVG`

1. I'm going to plot a chart using `OpenVG`. I read documentation and I can't find how to write a single pixel (something like `putpixel` in `Pascal`). I found one solution: draw a short line (1 pix line) but is not satisfied solution for me.
2. Load PNG file. `OpenVG` support only `jpeg` files but `jpegs` don't have alpha channel. I read `*.png` by `libPNG` and I don't know how to cast to `vgImage`. Have You any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In this project https://github.com/go4shoe/PiAVSignalGenerator I wrapped openVG into a fairly straight forward C++ interface.